# Who is the highest rated Strategema player in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The Zakdorn master strategist Sirna Kolrami is rated as 3rd level Grand Master; 
Data's record playing above Grand Master level is 1-1 (1 loss 100-81 and 1 win by opponent resignation, both games against Kolrami) 
note: though he demonstrated skill above GM level, he has not established a 'norm' so holds no title. (TNG 2x21: "Peak Performance")

Is there anyone else with a higher or equal Strategema rating to Kolrami?

Comment: A more interesting question would be "Where were the Zakdorn when the Federation was fighting the Dominion?"  And probably about as (un)answerable.

Comment: @kyle - there are extensive references to the Zakdorn in the trek books. During the dominion war they supplied strategists, officers and (for some reason) accountants to the Federation

Comment: @Richard They may have needed accountants to manage interactions with other sovereign nations, likely for supplies and raw materials. The loss of territory, the sacking of Betazed, the attack on Earth and the destruction of so many ships would have put a strain on even the Federation. War is an expensive business.

Comment: @Xantec - I was rather meaning that tactical expertise doesn't necessarily seem to go hand-in-hand with competence in bookkeeping.

Comment: @Richard I bet it does when dealing with Ferengi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no further TV or Film references to the game of "strategema".

I've scanned the trek books and found a few *very brief* references to strategema, but nothing that sheds any light on the ranking system;

- In [Deny Thy Father](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743464095); We learn that Will Riker played it at Starfleet academy;

> *He went to classes, he did homework, **he played strategema** and
>   racquetball and poker and parrises squares*

- In [The Red King](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Red_King); We learn that Will Riker prefers *chess* to strategema.

> *Riker eyed the board, its sixty-four spaces pregnant with unrealized
>   possibilities. True, chess had never seized his imagination in quite
>   the way poker had, **but the ancient game nevertheless satisfied a need
>   for tactical one-up-manship in ways that made even fast-paced
>   strategema tournaments pale in comparison.***

Given the lack of other evidence (and assuming that the scoring system works the same way as professional chess) we're left to conclude that out of the four players we know about, Kolrami is the top player in the Trek universe with a record of two wins (versus Riker and Data) and one loss by resignation. Data is the next highest rated (with one win by resignation and one loss) leaving Will Riker and Dr Pulaski joint-lowest ranked with a record of one loss and no wins.

Comment: I can't find any other examples of the game being played either, beyond Kolrami's GM status that is. So... Even though Kolrami holds the title of 3rd level Grand Master he actually has 2 verified wins; One each against Riker and Data, putting him at 2-1; Data is 1-1 and Riker is 0-1 against Kolrami. I don't see where Pulaski has ever played the game. This means that Data is the second best and possibly the best Strategema player in the galaxy. Of course he would have to convince Kolrami to play the rubber match to decide.